# How to programmatically set a wxPanel derived class dimentions?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a custom control, derived from a wxPanel, which draw a bitmap in memory and then show it.

This control needs to be shown multiple times (in a column layout), and i want they have the exact size of the internal bitmap. But i can't find a method to set my control width and height. What am I missing?

(Using C++ and wxWidgets 3.0.2)

Comment: did you try SetSize()?

Comment: Feeling so stupid... I was thinking at SetSize but (using CodeBlock) i was'nt able to find SetSize definition (which is a thing i use to "test" if a method exist), and also not having this->SetSize in the code completition led me to struggle to find where that method was and finally write here :(

Comment: as Vadim wrote you should be using sizers for laying out controls and relay on it to properly calculate the size of the panel.

Comment: I need the opposite way: calculate the size (well, the height at least) of the panel based on the image it have to show, so that the sizer will keep the column of custom control as "tight" as it can.

@Igor: you gave the answer before, but as a comment. Would you like to write an asnwer, or should i accept the VZ one?

Comment: you can accept Vadim's answer and raise mine to show it was useful. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use [sizers](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/overview_sizer.html) to lay out the controls instead of doing it manually, but if you really need to do it like this, it's just a matter of calling `SetSize()`.